# Javascript input weird data shown

Tags: javascript, mysql, leaflet

I tried to shows some datas to a form from a leaflet shape, but it shows me very weird, and I don't want this. How can I remove that LatLng thing? Code:`

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    map.addLayer(e.layer);
    var points = e.layer.getLatLngs();
  puncte1= points.join(",");
$('#geo').val(puncte1);
});
```

` This is what I see in that input: LatLng(44.93294, 26.00524),LatLng(44.92395, 26.05433),LatLng(44.94351, 26.05776), and I only want to see: 44.93294, 26.00524, 44.92395, 26.05433; Shortly, only the coordinates. how can i do this? I use Leaflet Draw and a MYSQL Database

Comment: `points.join(',').match(/([\d\.]+)/g).join(',')`

Comment: Thank u very much man, it finally worked! <3 Can you please give me your Google+ ID or facebook? Thanks!

Comment: I don't actually use either (sounds weird I know) but I did post it as an answer if you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip the unneeded parts out of the string with a regex since the API docs don't seem to reflect reality:

```
points.join(',').match(/([\d\.]+)/g).join(',')
```

Comment: Hello! Can you please help me again @Jared Smith? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [Leaflet docs for LatLng](http://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#latlng) and it seems like LatLng (the objects in the ´´points´´ array) object you get back has properties `lat` and `lgn` that you can use to get the values directly.

If so, you could do something like

```
puncte1 = points
  .map(pos => pos.lat + ',' + pos.lng) // get only the relevant part for you
  .join(',');
```

Edit: Apparently the result of `getLatLngs` is different depending on what shape you draw. The above works for drawing lines. For polygons you get back an array of arrays. So you'll have to use `points[0].map` instead.

Comment: undefined and undefined it's the result of this..I'm not using google maps, I m using leaflet

Comment: Ok. Weird. Have you tried using the code i wrote for getting ``puncte1``?  Or what is the exact code you use when you get undefined?

Comment: Yes, exactly what u said.

Comment: And I only added the snippet that u gave to me

Comment: The problem is that my lat lng it s an JSON array

Comment: Could you give me a console.log() of your ``points`` variable?

Comment: Do you have a Google+ account or facebook to talk? It's more easy

Comment: I do. But I feel like we're very close to a solution. I just need to know what is in your ``points`` variable.
``getLatLngs()`` should, according to the docs, be an array of LatLng objects. And according to the docs, the LatLng objects should have properties ``lat`` and ``lng``. So you should, for example be able to ``console.log( points[0].lng)`` and get only a number. Can you?

Comment: Nope, it says ,,undefined"

Comment: Can you try to edit (and save)  a code example like this https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/Lscupxqp/  ,then post the link to the updated code, and tell me how I get ``map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(event)`` to run?

I think I need to interact with the code to be able to help. I'm very confused by what you are reporting.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I can't get your example to work. There seems to be unrelated errors that happen before the function is run.  
But if I add my suggested code to http://jsfiddle.net/ludohe/tpkt9kyu/15/ then it works. (Can't edit that fiddle though. You you'll have to paste my code in the right place to see for yourself.)  See this screenshot here: http://imgur.com/a/7Trqu

Comment: If you get it to work now, please suggest how I could have been clearer in describing the solution. Was there some misunderstanding?

Comment: I see now that it actually doesn't work for the polygon. 
But it works when you draw a line.
For a polygon you must first use ``getLatLngs()[0]``, because you get back an array of arrays. The first array in that array is an array of LatLngs.  I haven't used Leaflet so you problably know better than I why that might be the case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qpty4pow/ this is a new jsfiddle, at the console output I have LatLng and the coordonates, and I only need the coordonates...

Comment: Thanks that helps. Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/qpty4pow/3/

Comment: I saw you went with another answer. I still think you could learn something from this approach. I made a simple new jfiddle to illustrate what I meant more clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/8uc6az9m/

Comment: Thank u very much @jonahe it's easily to use your variant! Cheers! Now how can I show the polygon that I created and added it to a database?

Comment: Sorry @RobinsonChera, I can't help you there. I don't know enough about Leaflet or your database setup. I know there are plenty of tutorials on how to use  Mysql, but I can't recommend any particular video or article. I would guess there's quite a lot of Leaflet tutorials out there as well. 
Spend some time researching it yourself first, then you will have an easier time coming up with the kind of narrow/specific questions that people here are good at answering. Good luck!